# why Uiautomator crashes in getUiDevices()?

Tags: java, android, android-uiautomator

i am trying to write a testing tool: create a thread in MainActivity and call Uiautomator functions to scan and analyze the UI components. is that possible? why it always crashes in getUiDevice()?
thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question is likely not specific enough to receive a good answer. When asking questions, please include concrete examples of what you have already tried (code/config/CLI commands), as well as any error output. See this guide on how to ask for help on the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and here for how to format code, etc. when asking:http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Happy hacking, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [UiAutomatorTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiAutomatorTestCase.html) is **deprecated** and you should use [UiDevice.getInstance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#getInstance(android.app.Instrumentation)).

Getting the UiDevice requires an Instrumentation instance that cannot be obtained from the same Activity, that's why you need to do it from a test run from `adb`.